# how to make a validation in calendar reservation between the existing date in database if someone check the availability

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$begin = new DateTime( date ( "Y-m-d",strtotime( $results->arrival ) ) );
$end = new DateTime( date ( "Y-m-d",strtotime( $results->departure ) ) );

$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
$period = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval, $end);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
    $begin = $results->arrival;
    $end = $results->departure;


    if($begin == $results->arrival &&  $end == $results->departure ){
        echo 'This date is not available';
    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(\'#myForm\').submit();</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: my main problem if someone make a reservation between the range date of calendar that exist ex. june 30 - july 17(existed)...and july 1- july 15 new customer that want to reserve.. i want this also to make this date is not available

Comment: do you want to check a user already booked for the day?

Comment: are you using mysql???

Comment: hi fasil kk, i have the validation for the range date that already exist., i just want to get the validation if someone trying to book in between the date already exist. im using wammp server 2.2, and wordpress

Comment: Please check my MySql query. that will return, if dates already booked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a query like this(if you are using mysql). and just call this function with both date.

```
 public function is_booked_date($check_in_date, $check_out_date)
    {
        $query = "SELECT count(id) FROM booking 
        where ((check_in_date BETWEEN '" . $check_in_date . "' AND '" . $check_out_date . "' 
        OR check_out_date  BETWEEN '" . $check_in_date . "' AND '" . $check_out_date . "') 
        OR('$check_in_date' <= check_in_date AND '$check_out_date' >= check_in_date)) ;"; 

        return $this -> db -> query($query) -> result();

    }
```

call function like this

```
$check_in_date='';// your date
$check_out_date='';//your date
if($this->is_booked_date($check_in_date, $check_out_date))
{
  //Date already booked

}
else
{
   //New booking possible
}
```

Comment: yeah, the booked already return., and how can i make a invalid condition if someone make a book between the date range that exist

Comment: hi Fasil kk, thankyou for idea that you gave.. it's perfect

Comment: welcome. Please update this question, with a small description. it might be helpful for others.:)